# Software installation with pip3

Tags: pip

I installed software using pip3 but funny thing is I can't seem to find it.
I went to dash and typed the name of the software and nothing came up.
I've used pip3 a lot with Flask but this software isn't related to Flask and don't know where to find it.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip3 install python modules. Only a small fraction of the modules include Executable files for you to use directly, most of them require you to import them into your own python code.

Comment: Strange. That wasn't mentioned on the download website. So pip3 installs modules or I may say plugins for other python programs. I misunderstood this part. Thank you.